# QGIS Processing v.net.distance Error

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction. I am wanting to calculate the distances from a point to each point in another layer along a road network using v.net.distance. I have done this successfully in the past. However I now cannot get it right. All layers are in the same projection.

The steps I have taken:

1. Create starting point layer
2. Create destinations point layer
3. Clip road network to area of interest
4. Use v.net to connect starting point to road network
5. Use v.net to connect destination point to road network
6. Use v.clean (snap and break) to clean topology
7. Use v.net.distance to calculate shortest path distances

I am now getting an error that the layer is not correctly generated:
Loading resulting layers

> *"The following layers were not correctly generated. .../dist.shp You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more
>   information about the execution of the algorithm."*

Inspection of the log shows the following error:

> *"ERROR: Value  out of range for parameter  Legal range: point,line,boundary,centroid,area,face,kernel,auto "*